# Conditional Formatting for a row when there is a text disagreement between two cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I'm working on a conditional formatting issue. I would like the whole row to highlight if the text in the same row in columns B and C disagree. So far, I've been able to write conditional formatting rules that leave the cell un-touched if there is no data and if there is a data entry that disagrees with the text in Column B, but I can't seem to get the formula to apply to the full row.

Here is what I currently have:[screenshot of the document with conditional formatting rules visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKobD.png)

I'm working on Excel 2010. Maybe there is a way to use a logic formula?

I look forward to hearing suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a formula. Highlight the range you would like to format, create a new conditional format, select "Use a formula..." and enter the formula as it would apply to the first cell or in this case row.

In my case, I chose  the first 6 rows: `$1:$6` as my range. So in this case, I would enter the formula as if I were only entering it for my first cell. The formula `=$B1<>$C1` will check for inequality between `B1` and `C1` in the first row, `B2` and `C2` in the second row, and so on.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In case row 1 contins different column labels as text, the formula could be `=AND(ROW()>1, $B1<>$C1)`.

Comment: if you have headers, just change the range that you apply the format to, rather than changing the formula. If row1 contained a header, I would have changed my formula to "=$B2<>$C2" and my range to "=$2:$6"